# firebase admin code completions not working in vscode

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I have tried installing the typescript thing using :

```
npm install --save-dev @types/firebase
```

but with no luck .

There is no code completion or intellisense whatsoever for "firebase-admin" , "firebase-functions" . Whats methods can i use to fix this ?

I have tried adding this at the beginning of my node.js index file .

```
"/// <reference path="./node_modules/@types/firebase" />
```

With no luck here.

Answer (score 1):

The typings for firebase and firebase admin are normally included into the NPM package, just peek in the node_modules folder. I made a little demo repo for you with the most common settings. The code completion worked as expected, the compilation as well.

https://github.com/giespaepen/firebase-admin-demo

Comment: thank you so much for your work . Im not familiar with typescript . I use javascript for coding (index.js in my project) . does it work in javascript too ?